# inverse of a matrix belonging to the same set

Tags: matrices, inverse

Is it true that if $A$$\in M_{n\times n}$ then $A^{-1}\in M_{n\times n}$?
$A$ is a matrix, I considered it as true but I cannot manage to prove it.

Comment: How do you *define* $A^{-1}$?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ a matrix such that $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: If $A^{-1}$ is such that both products $AA^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}A$ make sense, then it must have $n$ rows and $n$ columns, right?!

Comment: Yes, this is true but I am still wondering about the elements of the matrix. I am sorry, I should have been more specific and write $M_{nxn}($F$)$, where $F$ is a field

Comment: Parhaps that your question is: If $F$ is a field, $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$, $F'$ is an extension of $F$ and $A$ has an inverse in $M_{n\times n}(F')$, does it follow that it has an inverse in $M_{n\times n}(F)$?

Comment: Well,I already know that $A$ is invertible in $M_{nxn}$(F), hence $A^{-1}$ exists. What I am not sure of is if $A^{-1}\in$$M_{nxn}$(F)

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that we are working over a field $F$ and that $F'$ is an extension of $F$. Suppose furthermore that $A$ has an inverse in $M_{n\times n}(F')$. Does it follow that $A^{-1}\in M_{n\times n}(F)$? Yes, it does. For instance, you can use the fact that$$A^{-1}=\frac1{\det A}\operatorname{adj}(A),$$where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$. Since $\det A$ and each entry of $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ can be obtained from the entries of $A$ using only sums, subtractions, and products and since $F$ is a field, $A^{-1}\in M_{n\times n}(F)$.